# Usercases for 'in addition' vs 'also'

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, phrases

> Today, **also** representing nations and other political entities, flags
>   are used to represent youth groups, athletic competitions, and
>   international bodies.

In this sentence the use of 'also' should be replaced by 'in addition to'. Is the choice based on 'ear approach' or are there specific cases where any one of them should be used?

Comment: There is a difference however I can't put my finger on it. Using also here is understandable by an English speaker though.

Comment: It was a question and using 'also' here was wrong grammatically. Sadly they didn't explain why though.

Comment: It is not typical to _begin_ with _also_, when neither thing has yet been mentioned. _in addition to_ can be takdn as forward-pointing, but _also_ is always taken as backward-pointing. One expects a **this** to be listed in the prior sentence, and the **that** listed in the current sentence, which has the _also_.

Comment: To properly convey what seems to be the intended meaning of the "also", not only would it have to be replaced by "in addition to", the items would have to be reversed, with an "also" later on (In addition to being used to represent youth groups. . . they are also used to represent nations and other political entities.)  But chances are, that was NOT the intended meaning! That's another reason the "also" is so awkward.

Comment: Honestly, I would likely replace **also** with **besides**. In this case, the use of **in addition to** has a more similar meaning to **besides** than to **also*.

Answer (score 4):

You use "also and in addition" to give additional information after something else.  So their place is before the secondary information, not before the primary information. However, it's right to use "in addition to or besides" before the primary information. So the sentence under discussion should be rephrased as follows:

Today, in addition to/besides representing nations and other political entities, flags are used to represent youth groups, athletic competitions, and international bodies.

Flags are used to represent nations and other political entities. But today, in addition, they are used to represent youth groups, athletic competitions, and international bodies.

Flags are used to represent nations and other political entities. But today, they are also used to represent youth groups, athletic competitions, and international bodies.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, additionally and also are linking adverbs that express a relationship between two clauses. They are also called conjunctive adverbs or transition words.  These words transition the reader or listener from the main idea in one clause to the related idea in the next clause. So really it is by ear but there is one thing you can do. Because most of the time they are interchangeable. Use in addition to or additionally in a more formal setting. Also is less formal so sitting on your back porch also. Sitting next to a hot girl also. But to do it correctly in a more formal manner in addition.

1. also, less formal
2. additionally, more formal
3. in addition, formal